# React native app upgrade showing icons misplaced in android

Tags: android, react-native

We are developing a react-native application. When we have updated the release app from the play store, some of the icons are misplaced at the other sections of the app in ANDROID. This is really strange for us. When I deleted the app and re install the application it will be fine. But when update the app the icons are placed somewhere in the app in Android.

Also in iOS there is no such issues.
In the earlier versions everything was fine in android and it showing weird results on some of the icons.

example :- If I place icon named "cart" it's supposed to show a cart icon, but instead I'm getting chat icon. But these icons are we are showing from the assets folder.
Issue is like this link :- (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29645)

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so, can you tell me where to look for a fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue for me also, Any solution for this?

Comment: Same here, was seeing it regularly when replacing apk's directly on device, but recently started seeing it through the Google Play Store upgrades as well

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in Facebook's fresco version 2.6.0, which was the default for quite some time.  Upgrading to version 3.0.0 or downgrading to 2.5.0 should fix the problem.

in android/app/build.gradle replace

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:3.0.0'
```

[image: Upgrade Fresco from 2.6.0 to 3.0.0]

sources:
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/releases/tag/v3.0.0
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2667#issuecomment-1476119354